# Get errors connecting redis inside docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, redis, redisson

I have a Spring Boot API Gateway service and a Redis service running under the same network in Docker. I plan to connect the API Gateway to Redis, but I encountered an error:

"Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.redisson.api.RedissonClient]: Factory method 'redissionClient' threw an exception with the message: Unable to connect to the Redis server: 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:6379."

If I run the API Gateway from my local machine, I am able to connect to the Redis service running in Docker.

```
24 connections initialized for 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:6379
```

Here is my Redis configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    @Bean
    public RedissonClient redissionClient() {
        Config config = new Config();
        config.useSingleServer().setAddress("redis://127.0.0.1:6379");
        return Redisson.create(config);
    }
}
```

I also edit etc/host added redis

```
127.0.0.1 api-gateway db redis
```

trying to connect api-gateway to redis when api-gateway run inside docker

Comment: In Docker, each container is its own `localhost`, so your Spring application is trying to connect to itself.  The linked question is about PHP, but it has a clear non-language-specific answer about Docker networking.  You should be able to set a Spring property like `spring.redis.data.host` to the Redis service's name in your Compose file (do not hard-code it in your application source).  Do not touch `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score -1):

I have the experience that `localhost` does not work when containers need to talk to eachother. I would advise you to try and use the IPv4 address of your DHCP by your local network i.e. `192.168.1.1XX`. You can check through cmd with `ipconfig` what address the machine has been allocated by your DHCP.

```
config.useSingleServer().setAddress("redis://192.168.1.[XXX]:6379");
```